# Limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{nn}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+2)}}+\cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+n)}} .$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

The Question: Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{nn}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+2)}}+\cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+n)}} .$$

The attempt:

I rewrote this as a series: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+k)}}.$ Then I tried to represent this sum as a Riemann Sum. The width of the partitions is represented as the regular partitions:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+k)}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{(n+k)}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k}}.$$

I am not sure where to go from here. Do you think I am on the right track?

Please I wants hints. Try not and solve the problem completely.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have ${1\over n}$, which is $\Delta x$. Now you need to take the rest of the term $\displaystyle\left(\sqrt{n\over n+k}\right)$ and write it as just a function of ${k\over n}$.

Comment: Just a heads up: I think you accidentally changed the sign in the denominator from the second-last summation to the last.

Comment: @alphacapture : Great eyes! Now he doesn't even have to do an improper integral ...

Comment: One more thing after my first hint: $\displaystyle {k\over n}$ will equal $x$ in the function.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: try writing out $\int_{0}^{1}{f(x)dx}$ in terms of the limit of a sum as the number of terms goes to infinity, and try to match that expression with yours.

Comment: That ought to be enough hints.

Answer (score 1):

Now
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}
  \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}} &=
  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}} \\
  &= \left[ 2\sqrt{1+x} \right]_{0}^{1} \\
  &= 2(\sqrt{2}-1)
\end{align*}